# Using Cygwin from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cygwin

I want to write in cygwin prompt from MATLAB. I've try with:

```
!Cygwin.bat
system('solve-field /cygdrive/c/Users/maria/Desktop/VEGA_X1.tif')
```

with the first instruction open the cygwin prompt, but don't write the second line in the cygwin prompt. I hope that is clear the problem. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `solve-field` a binary in the cygwin install?

Comment: `Cygwin.bat` starts a interactive shell. Are you thinking to pass a command to it ?

Comment: Paolo solve-field is a command that is not present in the cygwin install. Yes matzeri i want to write in the interactive shell " solve-field /cygdrive/c/Users/maria/Desktop/VEGA_X1.tif " from matlab code. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could do it:

```
>> system('C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -c path_to_solve_field /cygdrive/c/Users/maria/Desktop/VEGA_X1.tif')
```

replace `path_to_solve_field` with the actual binary location on your machine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paolo, i have try your suggestion but "/cygdrive/c/Users/maria/Desktop/VEGA_X1.tif" is not found. I solved the problem ten minutes ago by creating a .bat file with:

copy "C:\Users\maria\Desktop\VEGA_X1.tif"
%LOCALAPPDATA%\cygwin_ansvr\bin\bash.exe --login -c "/usr/bin/solve-field etc."

Comment: @oOLorOo If you have solved your own question then write an answer for it so that other users can benefit from it in the future

Comment: @Paolo: * "/cygdrive/c/Users/maria/Desktop/VEGA_X1.tif" is not found* — This is the file name and path you mentioned in your question.

Comment: @CrisLuengo What do you mean?

Comment: Paolo, sorry, wrong name. I wanted to tag OP. They're complaining about a file not found error, but it's the file that they specified in their question that cannot be found. It's not an indication that this answer is wrong.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ah got you, no worries. Yeah, looks like the path is wrong

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by creating a .bat file with:

```
copy "C:\Users\maria\Desktop\VEGA_X1.tif" %LOCALAPPDATA%\cygwin_ansvr\bin\bash.exe --login -c "/usr/bin/solve-field etc."
```

Comment: This doesn’t seem to make sense. I think maybe these are two different commands? Please revise the code and included the needed newlines.